# How to stop IIS assigning specific port when compiling in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Every time when I want to build my project, the localhost port changes? For example...  http://localhost:6611/

What do I need to do so that a specific port isn't assigned, like so? 
 http://localhost/

Comment: Publish your application in your local IIS server.

Comment: If the below answer resolved your problem, mark as correct or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are being assigned a port number because you are using IIS Express to run your application. To remove the port number, ensure that IIS is enabled, and then follow these steps:

> Right Click on Project, within Visual Studio
>
> Click Properties
>
> Click on "Web" on left hand side
>
> Under "Servers", there is a dropdown. Select Local IIS.
>
> Run application, you will now be using IIS. Please bear in mind, there may be additional application pool configuration.

[image: See this image for dropdown]